# How to initialize a bootable disk and keep it bootable?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, usb

I have a bootable hard disk from a dead Windows XP computer. I want to see what is in it and if I should get a replacement mother board for it. I hooked it up as a USB disk but it disk doesn't show up in the file explorer. Right click "Computer" -> "Manage" -> "Disk Manage" asked me to initialize with the loss of data.

I saw some postings on how to do it without losing data. But I also want to keep the disk bootable in case I decide to get a new mother board.

I don't understand the whole MBR thing, like what is in there, how to read and write to it etc. Some explanation would be very helpful and appreciated here.

Comment: I would try a linux live boot usb or [hirens boot](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and use one of the tools on it.

Comment: In times of Windows XP another interface technology existed sometimes called "PATA" standing for "parallel ATA" as opposed to "SATA" which is "serial ATA". 
You should add this information. 
Providing maker and model of the drive is helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to plug it in other OS, i usually recommend(and use) a linux machine to read old drives.

Comment: exactly my friend!  I commented.. you answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the whole MBR thing, like what is in there, how to read and write to it etc. Some explanation would be very helpful and appreciated here.

The "MBR thing" is basically a structure describing partitions, their properties and their location on the drive. It developed over time and to ensure compatibility the way updates were implemented are extremely ugly.

The best article on the subject is written in a German computer journal called c't in issue 6/2000. You find a comprehensive description in the book by Brian Carrier, "file system forensic analysis" but a lot of free web information is available as well.